# Bullet physics crashing because of invalid reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, bulletphysics

I'm making a game with bullet physics where I have a Platform class, which contains a btBoxShape, btDefaultMotionState and a btRigidBody as members. When exiting my game it crashes. I store the Platform objects in an std::vector, and I think this is the problem. When I push back more Platforms, the vector resizes and moves in memory. This means that whatever pointer to the shape and motionstate that the rigid body has is invalidated. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A std:deque will not invalidate the references.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options I can think of.

`std::array`/`std::vector` with a fixed size(`reserve()`), if possible

`std::vector<Platform*>` You should probably use smart pointers here, but basically allocate yourself and store just pointers in the `vector`.

Comment: I'm not the one storing pointers, Bullet does it. Its objects need pointers to related objects.

Comment: @CarolineBengtsson Oh I see

Comment: @CarolineBengtsson Does my new answer help any better?